# How best to fill the bottom of a PVC Tee with resin, plaster or some other material?

Tags: material-selection, food-safe

There is a tradition in backyard chicken keeping of constructing chicken feeders using PVC pipe. (See:
https://www.instructables.com/id/PVC-Chicken-Feeder/
https://www.instructables.com/id/PVC-Chicken-Feeder-with-Meter/ )

One of the key components of such feeding systems is a "135 degree tee" (aka "Tee", see image below or in links above)

We've used the system for years. It works well. But you do get some pellet wastage. i.e. pellets sitting in section 1 of the Tee which just sit there and never get eaten. Nothing bad happens to them, but it just seems a waste.

I’ve been wondering if there was some kind of resin, plaster or some other material known to the arts and crafts community that could be used to fill the space at the bottom of the tee. Perhaps overthinking it, I was imagining a two stage pour. First stage (area 1). Simple fill. Then once cured, fix the tee on an angle and do a second pour to fill area 2.

Ideally the material used would be relatively inexpensive and once cured would stay in place, be very occasionally washable and be "food safe" * for chickens.

- whilst bearing in mind that they are already being fed from a PVC pipe. However, I do wonder if for that reason, we shouldn’t use plaster or cement, or if doing so, maybe covering it with a resin, sealant or lacquer later? (in which case, what would you recommend?)

I'd value your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Operating with a two stage fill is a good start. Consider also that the dead space at the bottom need not be anything special, generally speaking. Cut cardboard, stuffed newspaper, just about anything at hand. Create your 1 and 2 shapes all in one step or in pieces, as you like.

Once in place, seal the top surfaces of 1 and 2 with a flat component, perhaps another piece of custom fit cardboard or two.

This now forms the desired surface onto which you can pour food safe resin available at craft stores and hobby shops and online resources.

The last layers are to reduce the amount of leakage into the mass below as well as to reduce the amount required. Even some modeling clay to seal the edges on the inner pipe may be required.

The food safe resin provides for safe pellet access. You can pour in multiple passes and angle changes to get the thickness you require.

Comment: Very useful. Thank you. Can you possibly tell me a little more (post a link?) about what I'm looking for in terms of food safe resin. Thank you again.

Comment: I used The Google with terms "food safe casting resin" and was deluged with plenty of results. You may find you have a local source or that you can only find what you need online.